# Update cache file if last modified is changed in service worker

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox, service-worker-config

Is there any way to update file(s) in the service worker if the last modified date time is changed? I have some images that change every 2-3 days and want to let the service worker know to update them.

I separated these images in the cache directory in the service worker as well.

```
registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.startsWith("/images/changing-images/"),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: `changing-images-${cacheSuffix}`,
    matchOptions: {
      ignoreSearch: true,
      ignoreVary: true,
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update resources in `self.caches` whenever you want, and you can do this from the service worker context, or a page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/caches.

Entries in the cache API are [`Response`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), which include [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers). The header that's probably most useful to you here is [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified), but it'll only be there if your server chooses to send it.

Assuming it does, you could implement what you want by checking entries in the caches when your page loads:

1. Get the cache where images are stored using [`self.caches.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/open).
2. Get all the items in the cache via [`cache.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/matchAll). This will give you [`Response`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).
3. Look at the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) in those [`Response`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). If their [`Last-Modified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) date is over a threshold of your choosing, use [`cache.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/add) to update the cache.